# What is the German equivalent to "to keep under someone's thumb"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom, colloquial

What is the German equivalent to the idiom [under someone's thumb](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+someone+under+someone%27s+thumb).

Even if not exactly, is there any phrase having similar meaning?

Comment: Note "den Daumen draufhaben" is a very common idiom and a near literal translation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would say *[(jemanden) unter der Fuchtel haben](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=fuchtel&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)* as an equivalent figurative expression.

---

For the record:

> Die Fuchtel ist ein Degen mit breiter Klinge. Schläge mit der flachen Seite der Fuchtel waren eine übliche Strafe im preußischen Heer. [The *Fuchtel* is a rapier/sword with a wide blade. Blows with the flat side of the *Fuchtel* was a customary punishment in the Prussian army.]

Comment: Die "Fuchtel" ist ein breiter Kurz-Degen (auch "Rauf-Degen" genannt). Unteroffiziere und Kadetten wurden bestraft, indem man ihnen mit der flachen Klinge der Fuchtel auf den Rücken schlug. Die unteren Chargen standen also "unter der Fuchtel" der Offiziere.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung! Danke.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a common phrase in all of Germany. I would guess that you will find quiet a few (especially younger) people that doesn't know what is meant.

Answer (score 8):

[Unter dem Pantoffel von jmd. stehen.](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~unter%20jemandes%20Pantoffel%20stehen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)

Comment: Good additional answer. I would add that this one to me has a little narrower context as in between a husband and wife, not something I would use in general.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin. Assuming hroptatyr also agrees, I'd appreciate if you could incorporate these thoughts into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Neben Pantoffel (vornehmlich im Hausgebrauch) und der bereits genannten Fuchtel spielt auch die Knute diese Rolle. [Hier ein ngram-Vergleich](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unter%20der%20Fuchtel,unter%20der%20Knute,unter%20dem%20Pantoffel&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=). Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knute) ist die Knute eine Peitsche, und als solches ein Kommunikationsinstrument - wir sind doch ein Kommunikationsfreudiges Völkchen! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "unter der Fuchtel stehen" or the opposite "den Daumen drauf haben" when there is no personal relationship between the participants. "Unter dem Pantoffel stehen", due to the mention of the very private, informal footwear ;), to me implies an intimate relationship.

- note: "den Daumen drauf haben" is to be the one with the upper hand. "Unter der Fuchtel stehen", just like "unter dem Pantoffel" relates to the suppressed one.